# How does this code neatly list information side by side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have this block of code that sorts data taken from a database into a nice ordered format for easy viewing. However I have no idea how it find out the spacing to add to make it appear as a neat table, and would like an explanation.

Please could someone go through it line by line and just explicitly tell me what each line does?

```
def record_disp(info):
a=[list(x) for x in info] 
table=[]     
lens=[] 
for x in range(len(a[0])):
    maxlen=0 
    for y in range(len(a)): 
        maxlen=len(str(a[y][x])) if len(str(a[y][x]))>maxlen else maxlen 
    lens.append(maxlen)
for x in range(len(a)):
    for y in range(len(a[x])):
        print(str(a[x][y])+(" "*(lens[y]-len(str(a[x][y])))),end="  |")
    print()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because "ASAP" is no way to address volunteers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to be used for a specific programming problem or software algorithm, or to ask about software tools commonly used by programmers and requires that the question be a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

If this is not what you want, look to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ThatOneRandomScrub no, it's really not.  CR doesn't do "explain this code", it does "improve this code".

Comment: @Riker You are right, that's what's outlined in their help center and I apologize for the misinformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten this so it is easier to understand, splitting out complicated code, and removing unused lines:

```
def record_disp(info): #define a function that takes the input data, info
    a=[list(x) for x in info] #turn the input list into a list of lists
    lens=[]      # make an empty list to store max lengths

    #loop with x values from 0 to length of first list
    for x in range(len(a[0])):  
        # get the longest item
        maxlen=0 
        for y in range(len(a)):
            maxlen=max(len(str(a[y][x])), maxlen)
        lens.append(maxlen)
    #for every item print it out table, formatting with spaces
    for x in range(len(a)): #for each row
        for y in range(len(a[x])): # for each column index in the row
            # the previously calculated column width (lens[y])
            # is used to work out the number of spaces needed
            spacing_needed = lens[y]-len(str(a[x][y]))
            # print one cell, spacing it out and delimiting with |
            print(str(a[x][y])+" "*spacing_needed,end="  |")
        print() # adds a newline at the end of the row
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is poorly formatted, as as it stands it will not run. Anyway, taking it line by line

Line 1: defines a function that can be run throughout the code

Line 2: casts object x in the list info into a list

Line 3 & 4: Creates an empty list called table and lens

Line 5: Creates a for loop. The range function creates a list up (but not equal) to the number itself (e.g. range (4) = [0,1,2,3]). The len gives the legnth of the list

Line 6: sets a temporary vairable maxlen = 0 (which is reset every iteration)

Line 7: Another for loop like line 5

Line 8:

Line 9: Appends the maxlen on to lens list

Line 10: Another for loop - same idea as above, but this time the length of list a rather than a[0]

Line 11: looping through each variable

Line 12: print out each string plus " " times by length of the maximum string minus the length of the current string (so "    ") plus an extra "  |" at the end. This is basically a massive fudge to get all the | lines lined up

Line 13: Printing a space between each one

This code is needlessly complicated...

Comment: If anyone would like to say how I could improve the above answer (particularly the down voter) - I would love to hear it. Thank you!

Comment: I agree that it's needlessly complicated, mostly due to iterating indirectly via indices instead of simply iterating over the list items. I suspect that you got the downvote because questions that ask for an explanation of code that wasn't written by the OP are generally not welcome on SO.